# Accessing Routes in Node inside in a Domain Name

Tags: node.js, proxy, dns

I have a node app which is up on running on port 3000. i.e say 139.59.43.234:3000.

139.59.43.234 is my server ip.

Then I went to go daddy and assign a domain name say mydomain.nik.in which is pointing to 139.59.43.234:3000/SomeRoute.

If i then go to my browser and types mydomain.nik.in then it works properly. I can easily access my route.

This is my sample code.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/SomeRoute',(req,res) => {  // Route 1
   res.send('hello nikhil');
})

// here i have another route which i wants to access.

app.get('/SomeRoute/:id',(req,res) => { //Route 2
   res.send('hello user');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Now if I go to my browser and types "mydomain.nik.in/someId" then it redirects me to the SomeRoute method i.e on Route 1.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I wants to access Route 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://br.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120), there should be a **Wild Card Redirect** option in GoDaddy settings. And it does exactly what you are asking for.